# How to play music using spotify api in .net maui, if I'm writing an application for android

Tags: c#, spotify, maui

I'm writing a simple spotify analog on android using the spotify api. Faced with the problem that I don't understand how to play music. As I understand it, the android spotify sdk will not suit me. I get an access token and can search for tracks, artists, etc. But I don't understand how to get a media file.

I tried to do it with queries, but that didn't help either

```
public async Task<bool> PlayTrack(string trackId, AuthorizationToken token)
        {
            var url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play";
            var playLoad = new
            {
                uris = new[] { $"spotify:track:{trackId}" }
            };

            var client = new RestClient();
            var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Put);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.AccessToken}");
            request.AddJsonBody(playLoad);
            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
```

here response has StatusCode: Forbidden

Comment: Have you read Spotifys docs for a 403 response?

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: you are getting an error from Spotify.  The first thing you should do is read their docs for that error to understand what it means and why it occurs